# Update Content page Controls on Master Page Timer TIck

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a master page it has

```
<asp:Timer ID="masterTimer" runat="server" Interval="1000" OnTick="masterTimer_Tick"/>
        <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="time" UpdateMode="Always" ChildrenAsTriggers="True">
            <Triggers>
                <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="masterTimer" EventName="Tick"/>
            </Triggers>
            <ContentTemplate>
                <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblTime"></asp:Label>
            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

and in code behind i have simple

```
protected void masterTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.lblTime.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("ddd MMM dd yyyy h:mm:ss tt");
        }
```

In content page i have

```
Dictionary<Guid, string> data = dataClass.DataDictionary();
```

and then i am creating a dynamic server control of Label type in Default page (content page). Server control has property of Text. Now my problem is, on each tick it does read the correct data means data dictionary contains updated data and it does assign it to label text property but its not displaying the updated text.

I am creating my CustomeLabel like this

```
    CustomLabel newLabel = new CustomLabel
    {
        Text          = "Label",            
        Width         = 200,
        Height        = 150,
    };
    this.Controls.Add(newLabel);
```

And below is the CustomLabel class derived from LinkLabel and it has below properties

```
public string Text { get; set; }
public int Width { get; set; }
public int Height { get; set; }
```

and

```
readonly LinkButton Label              = new LinkButton();
```

and

```
protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
{
  Label.Text = Text;
}

protected override void Render(HtmlTextWriter output)
{
  base.Render(output);
}
```

I will appreciate if somebody tells me what i need to do

Comment: Please show the code that creates and sets the text of the Label control.

Comment: @SteveWellens just updated my question

Comment: What purpose does CustomLabel server over just using Label?

Comment: @Sully, msdn have mentioned here number of points https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa651710(v=vs.71).aspx but i use it mostly for abstraction and my **authority** over its states

Comment: I'm asking what is the purpose of CustomLabel. Mainly, because the answer you chose below is using just a plain old Label. I believe you are having issues with CustomLabel because you defined properties that are already defined in the base class, without overriding them. So it is the base class properties that get rendered, not your "new" members.

Comment: No @Sully thats not the case, i haven't defined properties that are defined in base class my properties are different. And below answer just gives me what i needed and i think he is using plain label just to prove its working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might do it for you:

Child page:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPage.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="ChildPage.aspx.cs" Inherits="ChildPage" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="Server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="Server">

    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="MyUpdatePanel" runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:PlaceHolder ID="PlaceHolder1" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>
        </ContentTemplate>

    </asp:UpdatePanel>


</asp:Content>


public partial class ChildPage : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Label newLabel = new Label
        {
            Text = "Label",
            Width = 200,
            Height = 150,
        };
        newLabel.Text = "Label: " + DateTime.Now.ToString();

        PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(newLabel);       
    }
}
```

Comment: It Worked!!! i wasn't adding to place holder i was adding to the this.control.add which adds to the form.. Thanks Steve i appreciate it